# Error accessing tweets using search_fullarchive rweet package function

Tags: r, rtweet

So, I'm trying to do some twitter scraping for my Doctorate Dissertation and I keep getting an error from the rtweet package.

```
install.packages("rtweet")
library(rtweet)

api_key <- " "
api_secret_key <- " "
access_token <- " "
access_token_secret <- " " 

token <- create_token(
  app = " ",
  consumer_key = " ",
  consumer_secret = " ",
  access_token = " ",
  access_secret = " ")

teste <- rtweet::search_fullarchive("lgbt",
                            token = token,
                            env_name = " ",
                            fromDate = "201401010000",
                            toDate = "202209012359",
                            parse = T)
```

I have an API for academic research purpose, so I can scrap up to 10M tweets per month, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: Twitter API failed [403]
Check error message at https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting
```

I checked and the Error says:

> **Forbidden**
> The request is understood, but it has been refused or access is not allowed. An accompanying error message will explain why.
> Check that your developer account includes access to the endpoint you’re trying to use. You may also need to get your App allowlisted (e.g. Engagement API or Ads API) or sign up for access.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to reach out to those who provided you with the keys to perform this? I would start there - I don't know what the SO community can do about this.